# FileManager fileExists() always returns false (iOS 10, swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, nsfilemanager

My App has to download user profile images from some web URLs.
Therefore, I'm creating an "images" folder in the user's "Documents" folder.
Creating the folder works fine, also downloading and moving images to this folder.

Before creating I check whether the "images" folder exists.

```
    var isDirectory: ObjCBool = ObjCBool.init(false)
    fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imageFolder.absoluteString, isDirectory: &isDirectory)
    if !isDirectory.boolValue { // directory does not exist
        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: imageFolder, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            self.imageFolder = imageFolder
            print("Created image folder.")
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

On every app startup `fileExists()` returns `false` although the folder exists:

> (lldb) po imageFolder
>
> ▿ file:///Users/[...]/CoreSimulator/Devices/CE56339A-2A1A-4105-97A6-828E96ADD341/data/Containers/Data/Application/C2CC9A93-E9A4-4069-9FB5-771DDAEAA454/Documents/images/

[image]

But `imageFolder.checkResourceIsReachable()` returns `true`.

> (lldb) po imageFolder.checkResourceIsReachable()
>
> true

The same is true for every other `fileExists()` call -> always `false` although file/folder exists.

Does anyone has experienced something similar?
Any advices how to debug this error?
FileManager bug!?

Comment: As explained in the referenced "duplicate", `.absoluteString` is the wrong method to get a path string from an URL, you have to use `.path` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Solved it.