# Why is NSFileManager.fileExists(atPath:) Always Returning False?

Tags: nsfilemanager

I am attempting to save an `NSPersistentHistoryToken`. Before the attempt to save, I check if the file exists, following Apple's documentation, *Keep Track of Your Place in the History*, [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/consuming_relevant_store_changes#3234028). However, `NSFileManager.fileExists(atPath:)` always returns `false`.

I copied Apple's implementation, which is provided in the referenced documentation, and contained it within a method:

```swift
func tokenURL() -> URL {
  let url = NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL().appendingPathComponent(
    "MyProject",
    isDirectory: true
  )
  if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path()) {
    print("==> FILE DOES NOT EXIST AT PATH (\(String(describing: url.path())))")
    print("==>       CREATING FILE AT PATH (\(String(describing: url.path())))")
    do {
      try FileManager.default.createDirectory(
        at: url,
        withIntermediateDirectories: true,
        attributes: nil
      )
    } catch {
      let message = "Could not create persistent container URL"
      print("###\(#function): \(message): \(error)")
    }
  }
  return url.appendingPathComponent("token.data", isDirectory: false)
}
```

I checked other questions about this issue, and it seems that others were using `url.absoluteString`, but I am using `url.path()`, which is what was recommended in the related answers.

I checked:

- [Swift 3.0 FileManager.fileExists(atPath:) always return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897844/swift-3-0-filemanager-fileexistsatpath-always-return-false)
- [FileManager fileExists() always returns false (iOS 10, swift 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815883/filemanager-fileexists-always-returns-false-ios-10-swift-3)

The output I see in the debug console follows:

```
==> FILE DOES NOT EXIST AT PATH (/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDD6A72F-C22F-4643-8366-01391DDC8EAB/Library/Application%20Support/MyProject/)
==>       CREATING FILE AT PATH (/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDD6A72F-C22F-4643-8366-01391DDC8EAB/Library/Application%20Support/MyProject/)
==> FILE DOES NOT EXIST AT PATH (/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDD6A72F-C22F-4643-8366-01391DDC8EAB/Library/Application%20Support/MyProject/)
==>       CREATING FILE AT PATH (/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDD6A72F-C22F-4643-8366-01391DDC8EAB/Library/Application%20Support/MyProject/)
==> FILE DOES NOT EXIST AT PATH (/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDD6A72F-C22F-4643-8366-01391DDC8EAB/Library/Application%20Support/MyProject/)
==>       CREATING FILE AT PATH (/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDD6A72F-C22F-4643-8366-01391DDC8EAB/Library/Application%20Support/MyProject/)
==> FILE DOES NOT EXIST AT PATH (/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDD6A72F-C22F-4643-8366-01391DDC8EAB/Library/Application%20Support/MyProject/)
==>       CREATING FILE AT PATH (/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EDD6A72F-C22F-4643-8366-01391DDC8EAB/Library/Application%20Support/MyProject/)
```

Based on the output, I expect the file to exist and for the file to *not* be recreated upon each access.

What am I doing incorrectly?